# How can I automap two lists based on a handle property with automapper 9.0.0.0

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to automap two lists with automapper, based on a Handle property. Similarly to an inner join. Is this possible with automapper 9.0.0.0?

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int Handle { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyObjectExtension
{
    public int Handle { get; set; }
    public string Description{ get; set; }
}

public class MyRichObject
{
    public int Handle { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description{ get; set; }
}

//and here my mapper usage:

IEnumerable<MyObject> MyObjects;
IEnumerable<MyObjectExtension> MyObjectExtensions;
IEnumerable<MyRichObject> MyRichObjects;

// mapping to a new object
MyRichObjects= Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<MyRichObject>(MyObjects);

// adding MyObjectExtension properties by mapping to the existing RichObject
MyRichObjects= Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<MyObjectExtension>, IEnumerable<MyRichObject>>(MyObjectExtensions, MyRichObjects);
```

This last lige of code works, but it probably maps the elements in the two lists one by one and I would like to map them  based on the `Handle` property.

Here is how I add the Automapper bindings for NInject in my NInjectDependencyResolver class, but how do I set up cfg.AddCollectionMappers()??;

```
            // AutoMapper mapping  
            kernel.Bind<MapperConfiguration>()
                  .ToSelf()
                  .WithConstructorArgument<Action<IMapperConfigurationExpression>>(
                        cfg => new Mappers.AutoMapperConfiguration(cfg));
                  //.InRequestScope()
            kernel.Bind<IConfigurationProvider>().ToMethod(ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<MapperConfiguration>());
            kernel.Bind<IMapper>().ToMethod(maper => kernel.Get<MapperConfiguration>().CreateMapper()).InSingletonScope();
            kernel.Bind<IExpressionBuilder>().ToConstructor(ctx => new ExpressionBuilder(kernel.Get<MapperConfiguration>()));
```

Comment: Try AutoMapper.Collection.

Comment: Don't add maps for enumerables. It can do that by itself. Just add maps for individual items.

Comment: Automapper 9 removed static mappings. This code won't compile with AutoMapper 9 unless `Mapper` is a property or field of type `IMaper`

Comment: The code I gave works but I'm not sure how the mapping in collections work with automapper. I'm afraid automapper maps the first element of the each list together, than the second one than the third one and so on... My two lists are not necessarily in the same order and so I want to tell automapper to map them based on the Handle  property.

Comment: As [the docs say](https://automapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Lists-and-arrays.html#polymorphic-element-types-in-collections) `When mapping to an existing collection, the destination collection is cleared first. If this is not what you want, take a look at AutoMapper.Collection.`. [That package](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection) was last updated 9 months ago though and may not be compatible with AutoMapper 9. You could use LINQ to join the `MyObjects` and `MyObjectExtensions` collections a single `MyRichObjects` in a single line, and probably get better performance too

Comment: Actually mapping to an existing list works fine, but it's just not based on the handle. I will try with LINQ.

Comment: It all depends on how many properties are there in the real scenario. For three, probably you don't need AM. For more, I would use AM.

Comment: @Ephie because that can only work if you use `AutoMapper.Collections` What does `just not based on the handle mean`? Are the objects updated by position? Overwritten? Something else?

Comment: @Ephie where is the actual AutoMapper configuration code? It looks like it's in the constructor of the `Mappers.AutoMapperConfiguration` class. There's no need to do that, just create the `MapperConfiguration` once and bind it as a constant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AutoMapper 9 removed static mappings so the question's code can only work if `Mapper` is a an `IMapper` property or field holding a reference to a mapper instance.

As [the AutoMapper docs](https://automapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Lists-and-arrays.html#polymorphic-element-types-in-collections) say :

> When mapping to an existing collection, the destination collection is cleared first. If this is not what you want, take a look at [AutoMapper.Collection](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection).

The library's Github page shows that matching by handle requires adding `Collections` to the mapper configuration and specifying the object equivalence with a single line :

```
cfg.AddCollectionMappers();
...
cfg.CreateMap<MyObjectExtension, MyRichObject>()
   .EqualityComparison( (oe, ro) => oe.Handle == ro.Handle);
```

After that, you can just call `Map` without any modifications :

```
mapper.Map(MyObjectExtensions, MyRichObjects);
```

This is quite similar to a LINQ Join. In fact, the [mapping implementation](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection/blob/master/src/AutoMapper.Collection/Mappers/EquivalentExpressionAddRemoveCollectionMapper.cs#L17) is quite similar to [Enumerable.Join's implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Join.cs#L71) - both methods create a `Lookup` table of the destination to speed up lookups before iterating over the source. AutoMapper goes one step further though and updates the destination objects with the matching source properties.

Notice that `destination` has to be an `ICollection<T>`. It can't be an `IEnumerable<T>` because that interface doesn't allow modifications.

An alternative to this would be to use a LINQ join between `MyObjects` and `MyObjectExtensions`:

```
var richObjects=myObjects.Join(myObjectsExtensions,
                               o  => o.Handle,
                               oe => oe.Handle,
                               (o,oe)=>new MyRichObject {
                                           Handle      = o.Handle, 
                                           Name        = o.Name,
                                           Description = oe.Description
                                       })
                          .ToArray();
```

**Important**

All this would make sense if the data is already in memory. For data stored in a database it's *far* faster and cheaper (and easier) to execute a SQL statement with a JOIN that will return the final object directly. That query can be generated by an ORM like EF (Core) or executed directly by a micro-ORM like Dapper.

Comment: There is no need to explicitly specify the generic type parameters. I think it looks a lot better without them :)

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I'm going through the docs and source for now. One can add that using `IEnumerable<>` is weird too. The important part is that a) there are no static mappers anymore and b) AutoMapper alone won't update existing objects

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for your answer. I use data injection with NInject and I don't quite know how to activate AddCollectionMappers() in my NInjectDependencyResolver

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I updated my question with the code of my NInjectDependencyResolver. Could you help me activate the AddCollectionMappers()? How should I do that? Thanks

Comment: @Ephie if you check the [NInject example in AutoMapper's docs](https://automapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#ninject) you'll see it's a *lot* simpler. You only need to create the configuration object once and simply bind it as a singleton with `Bind<MapperConfiguration>().ToConstant(mapperConfiguration).InSingletonScope();`. In your code it looks the `CreateConfiguration` method was replaced with `new Mappers.AutoMapperConfiguration()`. In any case, the call to `AddCollectionMappers` should go in the method or constructor that configures the `cfg` object

Answer (score 1):

I think that,in your case, is better use Linq. 
For Instance:

```
        List<MyObject> listMyObject = new List<MyObject>();
        listMyObject.Add(new MyObject() { Handle = 1, Name = "FirstName" });
        listMyObject.Add(new MyObject() { Handle = 2, Name = "SecondName" });
        listMyObject.Add(new MyObject() { Handle = 3, Name = "ThirdName" });


        List<MyObjectExtension> listMyObjectExtensions = new List<MyObjectExtension>();
        listMyObjectExtensions.Add(new MyObjectExtension() { Handle = 1, Description = "FirstDescription" });
        listMyObjectExtensions.Add(new MyObjectExtension() { Handle = 2, Description = "SecondDescription" });
        listMyObjectExtensions.Add(new MyObjectExtension() { Handle = 3, Description = "ThirdDescription" });


        IEnumerable<MyObject> MyObjects = listMyObject.AsEnumerable<MyObject>();
        IEnumerable<MyObjectExtension> MyObjectExtensions = listMyObjectExtensions.AsEnumerable<MyObjectExtension>();
        IEnumerable<MyRichObject> MyRichObjects;

        MyRichObjects = from myObject in MyObjects
                    join myObjectExtension in MyObjectExtensions on myObject.Handle equals myObjectExtension.Handle
                    select new MyRichObject { Handle = myObject.Handle, Name = myObject.Name, Description = myObjectExtension.Description };



        foreach (var MyRichObject in MyRichObjects)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Id: \"{MyRichObject.Handle}\". Name: {MyRichObject.Name}  Description: {MyRichObject.Description}");
        }
```

Return:

```
 Id: "1". Name: FirstName  Description: FirstDescription
 Id: "2". Name: SecondName  Description: SecondDescription
 Id: "3". Name: ThirdName  Description: ThirdDescription
```